# Cómo puedo comprobar que una llave corresponda a una clave en un diccionario?(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Usaré ese ejemplo ,espero me entiendan

```
Comida= {
    "verdura":"brócoli"
    "fruta":"manzana"
    }
llave= input(":")
valor= input (":")
```

Ahora lo que quiero es que ,lo que ingresé en `llave` y `valor` correspondan entre si
Si pongo `llave = verdura` y `valor = tomate` me devuelva un `True`, en caso contrario obvio un `False`
Esto lo quiero hacer con una sentencia `if`

Comment: un `if` evalúa una sentencia boleana, por lo que simplemente tendrás que usar un `print()` (si te quieres ahorrar codigo)

Comment: No entiendo si estás intentando comparar lo ingresado con lo que hay en el diccionario, porque en tu ejemplo "tomate" no está en ningún lado y te aclaro otra cosa, tomate por más que se tenga como común otra cosa  es una fruta, no una verdura.

Answer (score 1):

Primero hay que asegurarnos en que la llave se encuentre en el diccionario, si es asi pues solo faltaría verificar si su valor es igual al ingresado. Recordemos que la sintaxis para acceder al valor de un diccionario es así `dict[key]` (logicamente devuelve su `value`).

```py
#diccionario
Comida= {
    "verdura":"brócoli",
    "fruta":"manzana"
    }

#entradas
llave= input(":")
valor= input (":")

#verificamos que la llave existe y que su valor sea igual al ingresado
print(llave in Comida and Comida[llave] == valor)
```

La última linea devuelve una valor booleano (`True` o `False`) así que solo lo imprimimos, si quieres hacerlo estrictamente con un `if` podemos hacerlo de esta forma

```
if llave in Comida and Comida[llave] == valor:
    print(True)
else: 
    print(False)
```

Esto lo puedes colocar en una función pero cambiarias el `print()` por `return`

Answer (score 1):

Modificando un poco tu código

```
Comida = { "verdura":"brocoli","fruta":"manzana" }
```

primero declaro mi diccionario original

```
llave= input("Ingrese llave: ") 
valor= input ("Ingrese clave: ")
```

Después declaro mis variables donde almacenara mi llave y valor digitado.

```
#llamar a la función
print('resultado es: ',verificar(llave,valor))
```

Después llamamos a la función verificar donde voy a analizar y comparar si mi llave y valor ingresado anterior mente están presentes en el diccionario y también si la llave ingresada corresponde a la clave dada.

mi funcion:

```
def verificar (llave, valor):
    bandera = False;
    for llavecita in Comida:
        if(Comida.get(llave) == valor ):
            bandera = True
    if(bandera==True):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

En este ultimo código voy a verificar si la llave ingresada corresponde al valor ingresado ->  `if(Comida.get(llave) == valor )` entonces bandera marca `True`, y si no corresponde que se mantenga en `False`.
por ultimo verifico con condicionales si bandera a cambiado de valor o no y que me retorne `True` si a cambiado o `False` si no.